# How to pass an Eigen tensor to a function correctly?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I am having some trouble passing a function inside another function with Eigen tensor. For example, calling the Function1 in the main.cpp code and it works fine, but calling inside of Function2 is causing an error.

```
void Function1(Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& vark, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Kin, Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& Out){
    
    Out = vark * Kin * 1i; 

}
void Function2(Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& In, Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& kin){
    
    Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> out(nx,ny,nz);  
    out.setZero();
    
    
    Function1(In, kin, Out); //error in Kin as it's passed from the function
}
```

The error I get:

```
 error: cannot convert ‘Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>, Eigen::DefaultDevice>::EvaluatorPointerType’ {aka ‘double*’} to ‘Eigen::TensorEvaluator<const Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>, Eigen::DefaultDevice>::EvaluatorPointerType’ {aka ‘const std::complex<double>*’}
  152 |     return m_rightImpl.evalSubExprsIfNeeded(m_leftImpl.data());
      |                                                              ^
      |                                                              |
      |                                                              Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>, Eigen::DefaultDevice>::EvaluatorPointerType {aka double*}
```

I am confused why is this happening.

EDIT: I added the header file for the two functions:

```
void Function1(Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& vark, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Kin, Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& Out);
void Function2(Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& In, Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& kin);
```

Comment: The error does not seem to come from the code lines you posted (I don't see `return m_rightImpl.evalSubExprsIfNeeded`... in your posted lines).

Comment: @wohlstad I added the definition of the two functions in the header file. You can compile this and see if you get the same error. I keep getting this error with these same code lines.

Comment: Both these functions do not return any value (they are `void`). And your error message contains `return`, so it does not seem related. BTW - what you added are functions **declarations** (not definitions), and since your original post contained the defintions the declaratuions do not add any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Kin` argument of `Function1()` is a tensor of `double`, not of `complex<double>`. Yet, in `Function2()` you pass in a `complex<double>`. So the compiler complains that it cannot convert a tensor of `complex<double>` to one of `double`. Fix: Change the `Kin` argument to `Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>`, and also add `const&` for performance reasons:

```
void Function1(
    Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> const & vark,
    Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> const & Kin,
    Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> & Out)
{
  Out = vark * Kin * 1i;
}
```

Note: You might also find the [documentation about passing Eigen types to functions](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) interesting.

Comment: YES! wow I couldn't see that for some reason. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting a much worse template hell. This is a bit unrelated, but if you want to pass certain types of geometric operations as writable references (eg. passing reshaped Tensor to a function followed by chip, slice, etc... inside the function body) you have to use templated const TensorBase& as a function parameter and cast it to non-const in the function body:

```
template <class derived>
void func(const TensorBase<derived>& ten) {
    auto& res = const_cast<Eigen::TensorBase<derived>&>(ten);
    res.chip(0,0) = some_tensor_chip;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone struggling with this library as much as I did. The documentation is very brief to say at least...